# Base change system

Tags: number-systems, binary

the people in aldeeran planet use a base six system.

a]show how the aldeeran people represent each of the following:

i) 291.5 (base 10)

ii) 1010111 (base 2)

iii) 71.6 (base 8)

iv) 10A.4 (base 16)

b] how would the aldeeran people calculate 10110.1 (base 2) + 52.C (base 16)? show all your working using base six system.

- My Try -

a)i) = 2*6^2+9*6+1+5*6^-1 = 127.83

ii) = 1*2^6+2^4+2^2+2+1 = 87

iii) = 7*8+1+6*8^-1 = 57.75

iv) = 00010001010.0100 = 2^8+2^3+2+2^-2 = 266.25

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried? People are happy to help with questions, but please don't just copy-paste your assignment here.

Comment: i have tried it my self, i want to be sure about my answers, pls help me...tq

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to include your answers, so that people can give feedback and suggestions.

Comment: i updated @T.Bongers , im not sure about the b part, can you help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For i, you are converting $291.5_6$ to base $10$ (despite the fact that base $6$ doesn't have a $9$).  You were supposed to convert from base $10$ to base $6$.  We have $291.5_{10}=1\cdot 6^3+2\cdot^2+3+3\cdot 6^{-1}=1203.3_6$

For ii,iii,iv you have converted correctly to base $10$, but the assignment is to convert to base $6$.

Comment: tq can you please this question as well :
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683173/binary-code-decimal-bsd