# Binary Code Decimal (BCD)

Tags: number-systems, binary

I need help with the following question, my try is at the bottom:

Question : Using Binary Code Decimal 8-4-2-1 representation, calculate 6789 + 7156 - 365

My Answer : 1101010000101 + 1101111110100 = 11010100001100

please help me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BCD says you take each decimal digit and represent it with four binary bits, so $6789_{10}=0110,0111,1000,1001$ BCD, where I used commas to separate the decimal digits.  You add just like decimal, carries and all.  You may want to delete the leading $0$

Comment: This answer is correct thanks alot dear

Answer (score 0):

as using the Binary code decimal, 1 + 1 = 10,  1 + 0 = 1,  0 + 0 = 0 is the rule .
so the answer should be:
1101010000101 + 1101111110100 - 101101101 = 11010100001100

Comment: No BCD is not binary.  You translate each decimal digit into four binary bits.

Comment: oh thanks for that..